# If check not working

Tags: php

Following is my piece of code which checks wether 2 variables are equal or not.

```
if($Layer_GISfileId == $index1 && $itemID_additionData == $index2) 
{
    // $formHandler->addFieldValue($assetID,$entryarray[$row]);
    echo "\n-------------------------------Welcome---------------";

}
```

`$Layer_GISfileId` has value 19 and `$index1` has value 19. `$itemID_AdditionData` has value 2 and `$index2` has value 2. Both have same value so it should print *"Welcome"*. But it is not working.

Comment: What does `var_dump($Layer_GISfileId, $index1, $itemID_additionalData, $index2)` output?

Comment: try `if(($Layer_GISfileId == $index1) && ($itemID_additionData == $index2))`

Comment: Can you show more of your code.. no one is able to help you with only this.

Answer (score 3):

Variable name is case sesitive `$itemID_AdditionData` vs `$itemID_additionData`